# How to do bulk or multiple API calls in a frontend JS framework?

Tags: api, oop, rest, angularjs, httprequest

I'm building an API centric web application.
Our frontend will consume the API and after testing our plan is to release the API to the public.

I'm faced however with problems that in a normal MVC application were pretty straight forward but I can't seem to wrap my head around it in a RESTful way.

Take this example for instance:

- A company has multiple office sites which point to a specific address
- This address can be shared by multiple sites so Company has a one to many relationship with sites and sites has a many to one relationship with Address
- When you update an address I'd like to let the user confirm that for that they either want to update the LOCATION (so all companies that share that location through Site will be updated) or they just made a typo and want to create a new Location

How would I go about this in a RESTful way?

I can do a

- I first do a GET if there are other companies using that location
- Then I give the user a choice either to do POST (create new location) or do a PUT (update location)

  - In case of POST also create a new Site linking the new location to the Company.

An other example is if what appears a single form for the user will invoke several different backend entities that have to update.

Any examples or ideas?

Comment: It seems really dangerous to allow one company to update the address for other companies...

Comment: @NuclearGhost It's a CRM. You're managing your contacts. The user will only have a permission scope to edit companies which they have in their contact list.

Answer (score 1):

In REST, you might thing of the remote service as being the database. If you know how to do it in a generic MVC workflow, for fat-client apps it's the same.

You may want to deal with it on a "try default behavior, and raise attention if not possible" way, or with a "check what's possible and then offer possibilities". It's your app, it's your choice.

Personally, I'd go with a "try default and raise error if edge conditions happen". So in this case, assume (in the client) there is no other company with the same address, and use the corresponding endpoint (PUT). If the server detects a possible conflict, then return some error. The client will then prompt to the user what to do, and use whatever endpoint is chosen (POST or PUT, with a flag that enforces the update)